# How to stop the time from running after pressing "stop" on stopwatch

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-handling, stopwatch

I have created this stopwatch and it runs pretty well. The only problem that I am having is that whenever I click my "stop" button, the time stops on the screen but it is still running in the background.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? I want the timer to stop on its current time, then when I click "start", it resumes from the time it was stopped on.

Im thinking maybe create a "new Date()" variable before the update function and another "new Date()" variable inside of the update function and somehow subtract those to get the current date. But I cannot figure that out either.

```js
start = document.getElementById('Start');
        stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
        let watchRunning = false;

        Start.addEventListener('click', startHandler);
        Stop.addEventListener('click', stopHandler);

        function startHandler() {
            if (!watchRunning) {
                watchRunning = setInterval(update, 70);
            }
        }
        function stopHandler() {
            clearInterval(watchRunning);
            watchRunning = null;
        }

        update();
        var seconds;
        var milliseconds;
        var d;

        function update() {
            d = new Date();
            seconds = d.getSeconds();
            milliseconds = Math.floor((d.getMilliseconds() / 10));

            if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + ".0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + ".0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + "." + milliseconds;
            }
        }
```

```css
#Time {
            background-color: yellow;
            max-width: 2.3%;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
    <button id="Start">Start</button>
    <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
    <h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
    <p id="Time"></p>
```

Try running the snippet and you will see what I mean. The time doesn't stop "running" after I click stop, and when I click start it resumes as if it was never stopped.

Answer (score 1):

```
clearTimeout( return ID of setTimeout() );
```

clearTime variable is returned as a value by the setTimeout( ) timing method, which can be pass to the clearTimeout( ID ) as an ID to reference it - clearTimeout( clearTime );

How It Works

Whenever the clearTimeout( ) timing method is called on a setTimeout( ) timing method that is active, the clearTimeout( ) timing method will stop the execution of the setTimeout( ) timing method but without destroying its execution entirely.

The setTimeout( ) timing method is left idle during the period that the clearTimeout( ) timing method is called, and when you re-execute the setTimeout( ) timing method, it will start from the point its execution was stopped, not starting all over from the beginning.

You're good to go!

Comment: Where would I put that in my code? Anywhere I try inserting it, it makes my timer disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `setInterval` to run your code to update the stopwatch instead of relying on a `Date`; you can not stop the `Date` from changing, so even though you stopped updating your stopwatch, the seconds are still ticking by which makes it seem like your stopwatch never stopped.

```css
#Time {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 2.3%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
<button id="Start">Start</button>
<button id="Stop">Stop</button>
<h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
<p id="Time">00:00</p>
<script>
var start = document.getElementById('Start'), stop = document.getElementById('Stop'), time = document.getElementById('Time');
function StopWatch(props){
   this.seconds = props.seconds||0;
   this.milliseconds = props.milliseconds||0;
   this.updateCallback = props.updateCallback;
   this._running = false;
}
StopWatch.prototype = {
  start: function(){
  var _this = this;
   if(!_this._running){
   _this._running = true;
    _this._intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
      if(++_this.milliseconds==100){
        _this.seconds++;
        _this.milliseconds = 0;
      }
      if(_this.updateCallback){
        _this.updateCallback(_this.milliseconds, _this.seconds);
      }
    }, 10);
    }
  },
  stop: function(){
    window.clearInterval(this._intervalID);
    this._running = false;
  },
  getTimeString: function(){
     var ms = this.milliseconds, s = this.seconds;
     if(ms<10){
      ms = "0"+ms;
     }
     if(s<10){
      s = "0"+s;
     }
     return s + ":" + ms;
  }
}
var sw = new StopWatch({updateCallback: function(){
  time.textContent = sw.getTimeString();
}});
start.addEventListener('click', function(){
sw.start();
});
stop.addEventListener('click', function(){
sw.stop();
});
</script>
```